# jqGrid subgrid is not expanding

Tags: jqgrid, expand, subgrid

I've followed the way shown in www.trirand.com / blog / jqgrid / jqgrid.html

but the subgrid was not expanded

This is my jqgrid code:

```
 jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            url:"../ajax_request/user_table_request.php",
            datatype: "json",
            mtype : "post",
            autoheight:true,
            autowidth:true,
            colNames:[
                "Kode Jabatan Pengguna",
                "Id Pengguna",
                "Username",
                "Nama Pengguna",
                "Email",
                "Id Jabatan",
                "Nama Jabatan"
            ],
            colModel:[
                {
                    name:"id",
                    index:"kode_jabatan",
                    align: "center",
                    width:15,
                    editable:false,
                    editoptions:{readonly:true,size:10},
                    hidden:false
                },

                {
                    name:"id_pengguna",
                    width:10,
                    editable:false,
                    editoptions:{readonly:true,size:10},
                    hidden:false
                },
                {
                    width:10,
                    editable:false,
                    editoptions:{readonly:true,size:10},
                    hidden:false
                },
                {
                    width:20,
                    editable:false,
                    editoptions:{readonly:true,size:20},
                    hidden:false
                },
                {
                    width:10,
                    editable:false,
                    editoptions:{readonly:true,size:10},
                    hidden:false
                },
                {
                    name:"id_jabatan",
                    width:10,
                    editable:false,
                    editoptions:{readonly:true,size:10},
                    hidden:false
                },
                {
                    width:10,
                    editable:false,
                    editoptions:{readonly:true,size:10},
                    hidden:false
                }
            ],
            rowNum:10,
            rowList:[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100],
            pager: '#pager',
            sortname: 'kode_jabatan',
            sortorder: "asc",
            subGrid : true,
            subGridUrl: '../ajax_request/grid_jabatan_request.php',
            subGridModel: [
                {
                    name : ['Id Jabatan','Jabatan'],
                    width : [55,200],
                    params:['kode_jabatan']
                }
            ],
            scrollbar: true
        });
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{edit:true,add:false,del:false,search:false});
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('gridResize',{minWidth:350,maxWidth:800,minHeight:80, maxHeight:350});
```

what am I doing wrong?
Anybody have any ideas?

I confused subgrid.js and grid.subgrid.js are they same?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should define `name` property for all columns of jqGrid. Currently 4 from 7 columns has no `name`.
2. You should not use blanks in the `name` property of `colModel` or `subGridModel`. You use currently `'Id Jabatan'` in the `name` property of `subGridModel`.
3. The data for the subgrid will be provided by url defined by `subGridUrl` parameter. You should verify that it receive the request and answer with crrect JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

When the main grid loads, all the subgrids will automatically be expanded with the following code:

```
 subGridOptions: {
    "plusicon"  : "ui-icon-triangle-1-e",
    "minusicon" : "ui-icon-triangle-1-s",
    "openicon"  : "ui-icon-arrowreturn-1-e",
    "expandOnLoad" : true,
    "reloadOnExpand" : true,
    "selectOnExpand" : true
```

},

Comment: The old question to which you posted the answer **don't use grid as subgrid**. It uses `subGridModel` which share `subGridUrl` for all requests. On making the first request (opening the first subgrid) the internal property  `ts.grid.hDiv.loading` will be set to `true` till receiving of response from the server. So the attempt to open the next subgrid will test `loading` and will just ignore the request. So one will probably see that `expandOnLoad` opens **only the first subgrid** instead of opening (expanding) all subgrids. Moreover `expandOnLoad` didn't exist in jqGrid in May 2011.